# how to define a pydantic model with a field that is a list of a mix of several submodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I am defining a large model with pydantic and I am stuck trying to define a list where construct multiple submodels, lets see the example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal, Union

class Model_A(BaseModel):
   type: Literal["A"] = "A"
   name: str
   size: float


class Model_B(BaseModel):
   type: Literal["B"] = "B"
   name: str
   size: float
   color: str
   value: float

class GeneralModel(BaseModel):
   name: str
   objects_list: list[Union[Model_A, Model_B]]


if __name__ == "__main__":
  
  user_list = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "objects_list": [
        {"name": "box 1", "size": 3},
        {"name": "box 2", "size": 4, "color": "red", "value": 5},
        {"name": "box 3", "size": 6},
    ],
}
  # I would like to obatain the constuction of each model, but my code only construct objects of the first type defined in the Union statement.
  order = GeneralModel(**user_list)
  assert isinstance(order.objects_list[0], Model_A)
  assert isinstance(order.objects_list[1], Model_B)   # Fails, construct Model_A instance
```

There is any way to solve this and let pydantic to chose the correct model type to use?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `pydantic` allows extra fields when building an object. This means that all your objects can be interpreted as `Model_A` instances, some having extra fields such as `color` and `value`. You can prevent this behaviour by adding a [configuration](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#extra-fields) to your model:

```py
class Model_A(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="forbid")
```

This means that your first and third objects cannot be interpreted as `Model_A` anymore, and will be treated as `Model_B` by default.

You can also use [discriminated unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-str-discriminators) as ndclt [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77727074/12175753), but it is a bit trickier.

Edit: I'm assuming you're using pydantic v2.

Answer (score 1):

From your answer, I guess that's due to the behavior of the [smart mode describe in the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#smart-mode):

> In this mode, pydantic scores a match of a union member into one of the following three groups (from highest score to lowest score):
>
> - An exact type match, for example an int input to a float | int union validation is an exact type match for the int member
> - Validation would have succeeded in strict mode
> - Validation would have succeeded in lax mode
>
> The union match which produced the highest score will be selected as the best match.
> In this mode, the following steps are taken to try to select the best match for the input:
>
> 1. Union members are attempted left to right, with any successful matches scored into one of the three categories described above.
> 2. If validation succeeds with an exact type match, that member is returned immediately and following members will not be attempted.
> 3. If validation succeeded on at least one member as a "strict" match, the leftmost of those "strict" matches is returned.
> 4. If validation succeeded on at least one member in "lax" mode, the leftmost match is returned.
> 5. Validation failed on all the members, return all the errors.

With the `type` explicitly given, you go on the third point.

My first idea was to add the `discriminator` argument to the list of object like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal, Union


class Model_A(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["A"] = "A"
    name: str
    size: float


class Model_B(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["B"] = "B"
    name: str
    size: float
    color: str
    value: float


class GeneralModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    objects_list: list[Union[Model_A, Model_B]] = Field(discriminator="type")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_list = {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "objects_list": [
            {"type": "A","name": "box 1", "size": 3},
            {"type": "B","name": "box 2", "size": 4, "color": "red", "value": 5},
            {"type": "A","name": "box 3", "size": 6},
        ],
    }
    # I would like to obatain the constuction of each model, but my code only construct objects of the first type defined in the Union statement.
    order = GeneralModel(**user_list)
    assert isinstance(order.objects_list[0], Model_A)
    assert isinstance(order.objects_list[1],
                      Model_B)  # Fails, construct Model_A instance
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that It is posible to make it work if I explicitly define the type in the dictionary... but I do not understand why...

```py
  user_list = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "objects_list": [
        {"type": "A", "name": "box 1", "size": 3},
        {"type": "B","name": "box 2", "size": 4, "color": "red", "value": 5},
        {"type": "A","name": "box 3", "size": 6},
    ],
}
```